# Hide the iOS soft keyboard AngularJS

Tags: ios, angularjs, iphone, onblur, iphone-softkeyboard

I need to close soft keyboard on iOS simply clicking outside of input field in Angular app.

I found part of solution:

```
    $scope.hideKeyboard = function() {
     document.activeElement.blur();
     var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('input');
     for(var i=0; i < inputs.length; i++) {
      inputs[i].blur();
     }
    }; 

<input type='text' ... ng-blur='hideKeyboard()' />
```

but ng-blur does not help me.

something like this doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

Found easy solution. On top level div  (root of project) I added:

`ng-click='angular.noop()'`

no need for code above, or anything else.